# How can I fix my C code by adding pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I added my code below. I created a 5x5 identity matrix, but my teacher wants us to Use pointer/addressing methods to display the matrix. I don't fully understand pointers and I have been having trouble adding it to my code. I understood how to create the matrix, but not with the use of pointers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

int main() {

   int i;
   int j;
   int ar[i][j];//initialize the array
   int ptr;
    *ptr = ar;
   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       for( j=0; j<5; j++) {

          //if i = j, the array will = 1 
         if (i == j ){          
           ar[i][j] = 1;
           printf("%d",ar[i][j]);
        } 

        //else it will equal 0
        else {
        ar[i][j] = 0;
        printf("%d",ar[i][j]);
     }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually created a matrix.  You're just printing rows/columns of values.  You need something like `int matrix[5][5]` which you then populate and print the contents of.

Comment: How would I create an identity matrix by doing that, though?

Comment: @user10016329 Do you know what an "Identity matrix" looks like? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix

Comment: @4386427 Yes, that's exactly what I need. That is what I get with the code I have. However, my teacher wants us to use "pointers" in the actual code.

Comment: You need to read about pointer usage in C and practice a little. Then come up with code where you attempt to solve this problem, share it in this question, and then you'll get more help. You are not using pointers in your code right now at all.

Comment: Your code isn't actually broken so adding pointers doesn't fix anything. As others have stated, you haven't created a matrix; you are just printing a pattern that outputs what appears to be an identity matrix. You need to create a matrix and modify the memory locations that the matrix points to. E.g. `int matrix[5][5]` `matrix` is a pointer to an array of arrays that you can use to assign individual memory locations `*((*(matrix + 1)) + 1) = 5; //same as matrix[1][1] = 5`

Comment: I essentially gave you the answer and then you went and concocted this. **Have some patience and actually read** what people are trying to tell you on here and it just might make your life easier.

Comment: @bigwillydos sorry, your answer wasn't showing when I posted that. I tried meeting with a tutor and that's what we got. I'm still lost, I can't get it to print at all...

Comment: @user10016329 sorry to hear that you are still lost, but my answer provides code that does all but the print out the matrix. This is your assignment so you have to do the work. Here's some resources on printing the matrix: 1) [example program](http://tpcg.io/hVOBtx) 2) [Tutorial on multi-dimensional arrays in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)

Comment: bigwillydos Thank you for your help. I ended up figuring it out. The second part of my assignment wants me to exchange rows 0 and 4, which I cant figure out. I think this is where I needed the pointers, not in the code to just print the matrix

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix my C code by adding pointers?

Minus a typo for your function call to `Identity`, your code isn't actually broken so "adding pointers" doesn't fix anything.

> I understood how to create the matrix, but not with the
>   use of pointers.

You say this, but you haven't actually created a matrix with the posted code; you are simply printing out a pattern that resembles an identity matrix.

> ..my teacher wants us to Use pointer/addressing methods to display the
>   matrix. I don't fully understand pointers and I have been having
>   trouble adding it to my code..

If your teacher wants you to use pointers to display the matrix, then you will have to actually create one. This can be done statically or dynamically. Statically makes the most sense for a beginner/student. You would do that like this: `int matrix[5][5]`

Understanding pointers is often one of the most difficult aspects of C for newcomers to pick up so that's normal. It's probably been said to you before but I'll say it again: a pointer *points* to a memory location. You can use that pointer to obtain the value in the memory location (aka *dereferencing*).

For example:

```
int a = 10;
int * p = &a; //p points to the memory location where a is stored

/* these print the same thing */
printf("%d\n", a);
printf("%d\n", *p); //dereferencing
```

How does this relate to arrays and matrices? When you declare an array, the name of that array refers to the memory location for the beginning of the array. Each successive element is located at some offset from the beginning, meaning the nth element is located at the beginning address plus (n - 1). Here's an example of statically allocating an array and assigning individual memory locations of that array:

```
int a[10] = {0}; //an array of 10 signed integers that have been initialized to 0
printf("0x%x\n", a); //prints the beginning address of the array a

a[0] = 10; //assign the 0th element
printf("%d\n", a[0]); //prints 10

*a = 11; //this also assigns the 0th element
printf("%d\n", *a); //prints 11

a[1] = 12; //assign the 1st element
printf("%d\n", a[1]); //prints 12

*(a + 1) = 13; //this also assigns the 1st element
printf("%d\n", *(a + 1)); //prints 13
```

A matrix is an array of arrays but all the elements are next to each other in memory so you can address the elements in a linear fashion: beginning_address + current_row * total_number_of_columns + current_column

Knowing this, let's change up your `Identity` function:

```
int Identity(int * ptr, int num) { 
    int row, col; 

    for (row = 0; row < num; row++) { 
        for (col = 0; col < num; col++) { 
            // Check if row is equal to column  
            if (row == col) 
                *(ptr + row*num + col) = 1;
            else
                *(ptr + row*num + col) = 0; 
        }  
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Now it takes a pointer to an int and the size of the identity matrix. To use it, we will pass it a pointer to the beginning of our matrix along with the size of the matrix.

Like this:

```
int main(){

    /* this needs to match your matrix dimensions!! */
    int size = 5; 

    /* statically allocate 5 x 5 matrix of signed integers */
    int matrix[5][5] = {0};

    /* modifies our matrix to make it an identity matrix */
    Identity(&matrix[0][0], size); //first argument is the address of the element located in row 0, column 0

    /* now go through and print elements of the matrix */
    //I'm going to leave this part up to you

    return 0;

}
```

**For more on matrices in C, check out this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/)**

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  // const
  int ROWS= 3,  COLS= 4;

  // variable
  int row, col;

  // 2d array
  int arr[ROWS][COLS];

  // fill pointer with first address of array
  int *ptr = &arr[0][0];

  // print the element of the array via pointer ptr
  for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
      if(row == col) {
         *(ptr + (row*COLS + col)) = 1;
      }
      else {
         *(ptr + (row*COLS + col)) = 0;
      }
      printf("%d ", *(ptr + (row*COLS + col)));
    }
    printf("\n");
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0                                                                                                                                
0 1 0 0                                                                                                                                
0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score -2):

Any array decays into a pointer when passed to a function. By passing suitable "size" information, you can use it as a matrix.

So all you need is the code below - this will pass  `a` as a **pointer** to array (size n) of int. Then you can dereference the pointer using simple array indexing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void make_identity(int n, int a[n][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (i==j)
                a[i][j]=1;
            else
                a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int n, int a[n][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int size = 5;   // Just change size to get another matrix size
    int matrix[size][size];
    make_identity(size, matrix);
    print_matrix(size, matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1
```

An alternative way to write the code is:

```
void make_identity(int n, int (*a)[n])
{
     ...
}


void print_matrix(int n, int (*a)[n])
{
     ...
}
```

it will give you the exact same result (though less readable, IMO).

In both cases `a` is a **pointer** to array (size n) of int.

Comment: How does this help the student who asked this question what pointers are? I also doubt that the teacher wanted the use of syntactic sugar here.

Comment: Is a VLA acceptable as a function argument? Was this code tested, or guessed?

Comment: I don't think "an array decays to a pointer" counts as pointer addressing.

Comment: @WeatherVane It makes no difference that the variable is a VLA. Passing an array of array (aka 2D array) to a function is perfectly fine like this and IMO the clearest way. "Is it tested?" It is … but try it a try your self. Remember to turn all the highest warning level for your compiler to see if you get any warnings.

Comment: @bigwillydos Any array indexing is a pointer operation. `x[n]` is simply just a short hand and more readable form of `*(x + n)`. It's always a pointer operation. It gets even worse when handling arrays of arrays (aka 2D array). Coding `x[n][m]` as `*(x + n*NUM_COLUMNS + m)` is hard to read and error prone. All in all - array operations counts as pointer operation because that's simply what they are. BTW "syntactic sugar" ? What...? This is be far the best way to pass a n-by-n array of array to a function. No sugar here...

Comment: @TimRandall Maybe you don't think so but that doesn't change the fact that any array indexing is a pointer operation. I'm sure a C teacher knows that.

Comment: Why do you suppose the teacher chose that form of words, if not to get the students to use something other than array indexing?

Comment: @TimRandall Because the teacher wants to tell the students that array indexing is equivalent to pointer operations. Something a C programmer must know.

Comment: We agree, I think, that `array[index]` and `*(array+index)` are two equivalent forms, and that the former is often more convenient, particularly in the case of multidimensional arrays. Given this common ground, how would you, as the teacher, word your question, assuming that you wished your students to demonstrate that they had mastered the second, more complicated form?

Comment: @TimRandall There is no point in teaching students to master bad coding styles. There is, however, a point in teaching them how array indexing works (i.e. that they are pointer operations). I believe that is (or at least should be) what the teacher was trying to teach.

Comment: @4386427 thanks for that. I use MSVC which has never implemented the VLA and now doesn't need to :(

Comment: @4386427 The "master bad coding styles" comment is laughable justification of your answer to me. As if the underlying constructs of the C programming language should be covered up because they are too hideous to be seen. Even with your new edits, you've done nothing to address the student's obvious misconceptions. Lastly, `x[n][m]` is syntactic sugar for `*(x + n*NUM_COLS + m)` and you pointed that out yourself but this is an assignment for a student who is still learning about the underlying meaning of `x[n][m]`.